# How can I set the directionality of different TinyMCE editors based on the direction attribute of the input they replace?

Tags: tinymce, bidirectional

I have a page with multiple textareas to be replaced with TinyMCE.
Some of the Textareas take arabic text, some english text. The textareas have the `dir`-attribute set correctly according to the input they should receive.

How can I set the directionality of the different Editors according to their textareas?
I can set the directionality for all instances like this:

```
$('textarea.advanced_editor').tinymce({
    ⋮
    plugins : "…,directionality,…",
    directionality: "rtl",
    ⋮
});
```

But how can I set different direction for each editor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the end I came up with this:

```
$('textarea.advanced_editor').tinymce({
    ⋮
    plugins : "…,directionality,…",
    directionality: "ltr",
    ⋮
    setup: function (ed) {
        ed.onInit.add(function(ed) {
            var direction = $('[name="'+ed.id+'"]').attr('dir');
            ed.getBody().dir = direction;
        });
    },
    ⋮
});
```

I used the [events-based solution](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3%3aevent.tinymce.Editor.onInit) like @Thariama supposed and referenced back to the `dir`-attribute, which I know to be always set correctly.

Answer (score 6):

In this case you will need different tinymce configurations - one with directionality set to rtl the other with the default.

UPDATE:

This is possible. You need to call this using the correct editor id

```
tinymce.get('my_editor_id').getBody().dir ="rtl";
```

Comment: This seems very awkward to me. Everything is the same but the direction? Is there no way to insert the direction dynamically or set it afterwards?

Comment: Allright, I will dig into this as that is not sufficient, yet. Thank you.

Comment: you could give the textareas a css class arabic and depending on that class change the directionality onInit using a tinymce setting

Comment: No, it's not a must to get or know the correct id. I'm catching like this:

`for (var i = 0; i < tinymce.editors.length; i++) { tinymce.editors[i].getBody().dir = "rtl"; }`

Comment: @Arda: this will only work if you want to change the directionality of all your editors. In case a single one stays with "ltr" you got a problem.

Comment: @Thariama With a simple if clause inside for loop, OP can easily filter for a specific editor (something like 3rd loaded editor should be rtl etc.) That's my approach though.

Answer (score 4):

I edited toolbar of TinyMCE toolbar editor and there I gave both the options ltr and rtl over there to use.

Did like `toolbar1: "ltr rtl | undo redo"` in the function LoadTinyMCE()

So here user has both the options of writing as ltr and rtl comes as a toolbar. Did it in version 4.1.7.

Comment: This answer is the most up to date